# Automator Mac - Service "New RTF document"

Tags: macos, new-operator, rtf, automator

i would like to know how can i create this service. I want that when i click with right button in service list will be "New RTF document". How can i do this?

Comment: What are you clicking on? Are you trying to get a new rtf document with selected text? A new rtf document created in a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a Mac App Store app called NewDoc.